# How can I execute several maven plugins within a single phase and set their respective execution order?

Tags: plugins, maven-2, phase

I would like to breakup certain phases in the maven life cycle into sub phases. I would like to control the execution flow from one sub-phase to another, sort of like with ant dependencies.

For example, I would like to use the NSIS plugin in order to package up my project into an installer at the package stage, AFTER my project had been packaged into a war file. I would like to do all that at the package phase.

Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't Maven execute plugin goals bound to the same lifecycle phase in the order they are listed in the pom? Just a guess, may be worth testing...

Comment: Don't know... I'll give it a try

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Plugins bound to the same phase **should be** executed in the same order as they are listed in the POM. Under certain circumstances (e.g. if you bind the same plugin to a phase twice, like the antrun plugin), this may not occur but this is a bug (see [MNG-2258](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2258) and the related issue [MNG-3719](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3719)).

Comment: but what if you specify them in unrelated blocks, such as the normal build block vs. a build block that's part of a profile block? There may be some plugins in the profile block that should run after those in the plugins block, but others may not.

Comment: This doesn't happen (at least in maven 3.0.4). I have two plugins with executions bound to generate-sources, one listed first in the list of about 6 plugins and the other listed last. However, the one listed last (which depends on the one listed first) always executes first.

Comment: Agree with matt5784, this is annoying :(

Comment: Also agree with matt5784 on this one.  Any known work arounds?

Comment: Work around: sort by desired order and reverse. Tested and works for me :)

Comment: The bugs listed are purportedly fixed in Maven 3.0.3.  http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-plugin-execution-order-in-same-phase/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. look at [How to perform ordered tasks in Maven2 build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450266/how-to-perform-ordered-tasks-in-maven2-build).
for some reason the different goals bound to a phase are stored in a hash map or other unordered structure which makes the execution order random.
my solution was to spread the tasks to different phases but I dont think there is much sence for it in your case (nsis packaging is not pre integration test).
you could do one of the following:

1) try your luck and see if Maven chosses the right order for you (you probably tried that already)

2) use standalone plugin - run the goal outside the lifecycle. something like:
    mvn package org.codehaus.mojo:nsis-maven-plugin:1.0:compile.

3) separate them into module: have a parent pom containing two sub modules, one - your war project and the other for the nsis project.

4) use a custom lifecycle by changing the  type, in your case you can use "exe". this is done by using a custom plugin extension ([guide to using extension](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html))

5) use the [jetspeed-mvn-maven-plugin](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/buildguide/jetspeed-mvn-plugin.html). I have never used it but it seems relevant to your needs.

hope this gives you new ideas.

Ronen

Comment: Thanks, but except for some "kinks" with the default lifecycle @Pascal is right

Comment: those are no "kinks". actually if you ask the Maven guys they'll tell you that number 3 is with best accordance with the "Maven way" that is the separation of modules and when you think about it, it make a lot of sense that creating a web application and an installer project are two separate things.