# Running a plugin goal before the default one

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

TL;DR: Using maven, I want to run a plugin goal at the beginning of the `test` phase, before tests actually run. What would be a clean way to do it?

---

I want to print a message just before the tests actually run. Hence I want to use the `echo` goal of the [echo plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/Maven-Echo-Plugin/) at the beginning of the test phase (to tell the user that if every tests fail, he'd better have a look at the `README` since there's a test environment he should set up first)

**Attempt n°1**

A simple approach could be to run this plugin in [the previous phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), `process-test-classes`.

It works, but it doesn't seem semantically correct to bind this task to this phase...

**Attempt n°2**

According to [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), `When multiple executions are given that match a particular phase, they are executed in the order specified in the POM, with inherited executions running first.`, so I tried to set explicitly the `surefire` plugin:

```
...
 <plugin>
   <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.1</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>test</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>echo</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <echos>
       <echo>*** If most tests fail, make sure you've installed the fake wiki. See README for more info ***</echo>
     </echos>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.16</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>test</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
 ...
```

But tests run before my message is printed.

So, to put it in a nutshell: is there a way to reach my goal, or should I stick to the "`process-test-classes` solution" even though it seems a bit "hacky"?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check the existence of the fake wiki before your tests? Apart from that it sounds like running integration tests and not unit tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @khmarbaise said, your solution is still hacky, because whole test looks like Integration Test and should be processed by [Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). Failsafe has nice phase `pre-integration-test` for testing fake wiki etc :)

Based on [Guide to Configuring Default Mojo Executions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html) this works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>1-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <echos>
            <echo>*** If most tests fail, make sure you've installed the fake wiki. See README for more info ***</echo>
        </echos>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>2-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is very odd for me ;)

> I have two plugins with executions bound to generate-sources, one listed first in the list of about 6 plugins and the other listed last. However, the one listed last (which depends on the one listed first) always executes first.

[How can I execute several maven plugins within a single phase and set their respective execution order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509513/how-can-i-execute-several-maven-plugins-within-a-single-phase-and-set-their-resp)

Comment: Thank you, both for the solution, for pointing me out the failsafe plugin, and for the link to the documentation!

Comment: Very nice trick, but it will output the following: 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test)
[INFO] Tests are skipped.

A better configuration would be to 'unbind' the phase:
<execution>
 <id>default-test</id>
 <phase>none</phase>
</execution>
. Also this can apply to any other plugin which might not have a skip property.